# how to keep the value of a column that has the highest value on another column with groupby in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'var': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
                       'value': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                       'input': [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3]})
```

I would like to keep the `var` for which the `value` is the highest by `input` and set the rest of the `var` to `NA`.

So I would like to end up with:

```
   df = pd.DataFrame({'var': [np.nan, 'A', np.nan, 'B', np.nan, np.nan, 'C'],
                       'value': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                       'input': [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3]})
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `max` for `Series` with same size like original DataFrame, compare for not equal by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and set new values with `loc`:

```
mask = df.groupby('var')['value'].transform('max').ne(df['value'])

df.loc[mask, 'var'] = np.nan
print (df)
   var  value  input
0  NaN      1    0.1
1    A      2    0.2
2  NaN      1    0.3
3    B      2    0.4
4  NaN      3    0.5
5  NaN      4    0.6
6    C      5    0.7
```

Answer (score 1):

`where` is a useful trick to set NaNs in a column based on some conditions.

```
df['var'].where(df.groupby('var').value.transform('max').eq(df['value']))
```

**Output**

```
0   NaN
1   A
2   NaN
3   B
4   NaN
5   NaN
6   C
```